# Uri permissions after the device reboot on pre-KitKat devices?

Tags: android, android-permissions

There's plenty of questions and answers how to work with the new API >= 19 permission model but I've been wondering about the opposite -- how I'm supposed to read file content from a Content Provider which has granted a read/write permission to my app and the device reboots for some reason?

Android documentations [says](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client):

> `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is not intended to be a replacement for
>   `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. The one you should use depends on the needs of
>   your app:
>
> Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` if you want your app to simply read/import
>   data. With this approach, the app imports a copy of the data, such as
>   an image file.
>
> Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` if you want your app to have
>   long term, persistent access to documents owned by a document
>   provider. An example would be a photo-editing app that lets users edit
>   images stored in a document provider.

OK, so I have a photo-editing app running on API 16, what are my option to access (write to) this file? It seems very strange to ask the user to navigate to Gallery every single time he wants to continue his work, doesn't it? On the same token, making a copy in app's private folder doesn't seem like a good idea (think of big pictures/videos...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mechanism for persistent access to a URI across reboots prior to API 19 and the introduction of [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) - that was the exact reason the API was introduced.

You'll have to make a copy in your own storage space if you want to allow multiple editing sessions on the same item.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the Gallery app work only because it reads *files* out of external public storage directories, i.e. not relying on Uris and permissions to access them?

Comment: There are many Gallery apps (most manufacturers make their own), so behavior may certainly be different between each. However, in general there are two things to keep in mind: 1) when the Gallery app is both the display and editing app, there's no URI permissions needed within the same app and 2) most Gallery apps use the [MediaStore ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) which does not use URI permissions but instead relies solely on the read/write external storage permissions.